# Huge percentage increase

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The unit of currency in Bolivia used to be the peso boliviano. In 1986, the inflation rate in Bolivia was 8000% annually.

Let P be the initial price of an item in Bolivia in 1986. Write a function for the cost of this item, C, in terms of the number of years, t, since 1986.

I tried: $P+8000^t$ And that is wrong?

The second part of the problem is this:

 How many months will it take the cost of the item to double?
(Round the answer down to the nearest month. Your answer must include units to receive full credit.)

So when I have the first part I just make 2p = (function) and that will be the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(t)$ be the cost for the year $t$. Then, we have

$C(0) = P$ and $C(t) = C(t - 1) \cdot 8100\text{%}$ for $t \ge 1$.

So, $C(t) = P \cdot 8100\text{%}^t$

Answer (score 1):

After one year, the price is $\dfrac{8000}{100}P+P$, and after $t$ years, the price is 
$$\left(\dfrac{8100}{100}\right)^tP=81^tP$$

Answer (score 0):

With your function, an item will add $8000$ in the first year, regardless of its starting price, and $64,000,000$ in two years. The answer needs to be proportional to $P$. Also note that an increase of $8000\%$ is an increase of $80$ times, so what would an item that now costs $2$ be in a year?